# Spring and OpenEJB using the same Entity Manager

Tags: spring, persistence, openjpa, openejb, apache-tomee

How can I get Spring beans and EJBs, both of which are in a TomEE container, to use a common persistence context?

I am trying to incorporate several EJB components into a predominantly Spring application.  Eventually everything will be either EJB3 or Spring, but for the foreseeable future I live in a hybrid world.

1. DataSources are defined in the applications's resources.xml file
2. PersistenceUnit is defined in a persistence.xml file that references the datasources
3. Spring accesses the container transaction manager and EntityManagerFactory as follows in the applicationContext.xml file:

   ```
   <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj"
       transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

   <bean id="transactionManager"
       class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
   <property name="transactionManagerName"
           value="java:comp/env/comp/TransactionManager"/>
   </bean>

   <jee:jndi-lookup id="entitiesEntityManagerFactory" 
        jndi-name="persistence/entitiesPersistenceUnit"
        resource-ref="true"/>
   ```
4. Spring and EJB components have no problem finding the transaction manager, entitymanagers, or data sources;  anything that is entirely Spring or entirely EJB works fine.  But...
5. There are a couple of points at which a transaction must start in an EJB and then propagate to methods invoked on a Spring bean, at which point the Spring bean complains that it has its hands on unmanaged entities.  I annotate the initiating method in the EJB with `@TransactionAttribute` and the receiving method in the Spring Bean with `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.Mandatory)`; the Spring bean does not complain about not being in a transactional context, but somehow the persistence context does not follow, as verified by `this.entityManager.contains(this)` returning false.

The problem seems to lie in the way Spring and OpenEJB treat the injection of an entity manager. If I include the same code in an EJB and in a Spring bean:

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManger em;
```

In the EJBs, `em` is injected with an instance of `org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager`

whereas in Spring, `em` is injected with something that prints like this:

`shared EntityManager proxy for target factory [org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory@1ca24fe7]`

Both the `JtaEntityManager` and the Proxy contain the same underlying instance of `org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory`

I have read everything I can find on Spring / EJB integration, but have not found anything specific dealing with shared persistence context or transactions crossing from EJBs into Spring beans.